# Laravel table name multiple words

Tags: laravel-5

I need help with table name in laravel 5.4 please.

I have a table called product_categories and a model called ProductCategory.

In the model I specify: protected $table = 'product_categories';

When I try to save a category I get this error:

Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'highland.product-categories' why is it looking for a table called product-categories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the problem, it was in my validation, checking for unique name:

'name' => 'required|unique:product-categories|string'

Changed it to:

'name' => 'required|unique:product_categories|string'